# Windows 7 wanting to write various files to a blank disk. But where are they coming from?

Tags: windows-7

I just bought some DVDs from a shop, and I guess they are blank.

From the cmd prompt, I do D: (and if that were to work i'd do DIR). And when I do D: it won't work it says "incorrect function". Which is good that means here that it is blank(And not just blank it's not even accessible).    That's from the cmd prompt.

But Windows 7 when I put it in,
then this screen shows

[image]

If I then choose "Burn files to disc".

Then this screen comes up

[image]

And if I choose Next, then this comes up

[image]

So, it says "files ready to be written to disc" (so no doubt not yet written to the disk).
And has  AUDIO_TS, VIDEO_TS desktop.ini and memtest-86.iso

Why on earth memtest86.iso?  is that normal for Windows to want to write that by default?!?!

I know what memtest is, it's an ancient program still used, that people run early in the boot process to test RAM.  I find it surprising that Windows would want to stick an image file, iso file, onto the CD, along with other folders for a playable DVD.

And as a side note, I also find it strange that Windows wants to write those folders AUDIO_TS and VIDEO_TS when I haven't provided a video-playable DVD.. like

Comment: I'm pretty sure its just showing you files you have previously queued up to burn to disk in the past.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes it was but even then, why and what to do. But I posted an answer 4h ago.

Answer (score 0):

The VIDEO_TS folder showed an old movie.

It was because of files here(in this appdata windows burn directory), the files showed/show with DIR /A.

in

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn
```

e.g. this file

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Burn\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_0.vob
```

I cleared within that directory and then it was fine